# How can I hide/remove ScrollBar in ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

If the content of the ScrollView is bigger than the screen, while scrolling, the scrollbar on the side appears. I couldn't find anything to help me hide it.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can use `showsIndicators: false` to hide the indicator:

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You just have to use the scrollView initializer and set the parameter showsIndicators property to false within the initializer only.

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
     //your content for scrollView
}
```

Hope this has resolved your query.

Answer (score 6):

if you need to hide both scrollers:

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
  //your code
}
```

__

If you need to hide only one scroller, but to have ability to scroll in both directions:

need to use [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect):

```
ScrollView() {
    // Some Content
}
.introspectScrollView{ 
    $0.hasHorizontalScroller = false
    $0.hasVerticalScroller = true
}
```

as result:

- horisontal scroller invisible
- vertical scroller visible;

Answer (score 1):

#### Show / Hide Indicators in ScrollView SwiftUI

Hide Indicators in ScrollView SwiftUI

```
  ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false) {
  //your code
  }
```

Show Indicators in ScrollView SwiftUI

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: true) {
  //your code
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 16, you can use:

```
ScrollView {
    ...
}
.scrollIndicators(.hidden)
```